# Plotting in R using ggplot2 and latex

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, latex, eps

I am plotting a bar graph in R and exporting as eps, the plot looks excellent. When i add it to my latex file it messes up the font any recommendations ?

Here is the original eps
[image]

Here is the image in the pdf produced in the latex, i am doing

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{file.eps}

[image]

Comment: try the tikzDevice?

Comment: Doesnt seem to give nice plot as eps for some reason...

Comment: sounds like a viewer issue, maybe the file is fine but the viewer is confused about fonts? It would help if you described your latex process (and also,  what happens if you use pdf and pdflatex)

Comment: try also to embed the fonts in the eps file

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment: how do we embed fonts when exporting from R ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your controlling the width of the picture which is messing up the aspect ratio? In LaTeX I usually use [scale=.X] and play around a bit until it's the correct size. That way the aspect ratio is kept the same.